# Adding alternating values from two tuples to an empty list (python3)

Tags: python, list, tuples

Given the tuples : tuple1 = (3,5,16,35,75) and tuple2 = (1,19,28,44,64), I would like the output to be list5=[3, 1, 5, 19, 16, 28, 35, 44, 75, 64]. This is what I've done but I know this isn't the best way to do it.

```
list5 =[]
list5.append(tuple1[0])
list5.append(tuple2[0])
list5.append(tuple1[1])
list5.append(tuple2[1])
list5.append(tuple1[2])
list5.append(tuple1[3])
list5.append(tuple2[3])
list5.append(tuple1[4])
list5.append(tuple2[4])
print(list5)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can `zip` the two tuples then create a single list using a list comprehension.

```
>>> tuple1 = (3,5,16,35,75)
>>> tuple2 = (1,19,28,44,64)
>>> [i for j in zip(tuple1, tuple2) for i in j]
[3, 1, 5, 19, 16, 28, 35, 44, 75, 64]
```

If there is a chance the tuples are of uneven length you can use `itertools.zip_longest` instead of `zip`

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> tuple1 = (3,5,16,35,75)
>>> tuple2 = (1,19,28,44,64,89,101)
>>> [i for j in zip_longest(tuple1, tuple2) for i in j if i is not None]
[3, 1, 5, 19, 16, 28, 35, 44, 75, 64, 89, 101]
```

Comment: with zip_longest, tuples of unequal length will work, unless they contain `None` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` and `zip` to support tuples of arbitrary size -

`list5 = list(itertools.chain(*[[t1, t2] for t1, t2 in zip(tuple1, tuple2)]))`

**Update**
Following the comments I think -
`list(chain(*zip(tuple1, tuple2)))`
is the most elegant way

Comment: same as `list(chain(*zip(tuple1, tuple2)))`

Comment: if the lengths of two tuples are not equal, this may result in incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using zip() is a common way to approach this but if one of the tuples is longer than the other, you'll need a bit of extra work:

```
tuple1 = (3,5,16,35,75,98,99,100)
tuple2 = (1,19,28,44,64)

list5  = [n for z in zip(tuple1,tuple2) for n in z]    # alternate values
list5 += [*tuple1[len(tuple2):],*tuple2[len(tuple1):]] # longer tuple

print(list5)
[3, 1, 5, 19, 16, 28, 35, 44, 75, 64, 98, 99, 100]
```

It possible to do it without using zip, but it's a bit more convoluted:

```
 list5  = [t[i] for i in range(max(len(tuple1),len(tuple2))) 
                for t in (tuple1,tuple2) if i<len(t)]
```